# Git rebase and nested branches

Tags: git, git-rebase

How do I use `git rebase --onto` to transform the Before case into the After case?

```
          Before                           After
    A---B---C---F---G (main)        A---B---C---F------------G (main)
             \                               \                \
              D        (branch-A)             D  (branch-A)     H---I (branch-C)
               \                               \
                E       (branch-B)              E  (branch-B)
                 \
                  H---I (branch-C)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an easy one

```
git rebase branch-b branch-c --onto main
```